# SQLConnections 100 + instance problem in database

Tags: sql-server

I am using a SQL Server Database in my CRM Project.  It is not Microsoft CRM, it is a simple BPO website that 100+ users used to work on.  Sometimes there are more than 100 users logged in, and works properly.  However it gives me an error `Server page not responding` after 1-2 minutes and everything stops working.  After some time it again continues working.

Our Windows admin said this:

> Our Windows shared Servers allow up to 150 connections MAX at a time. Your database alone was using 100 SQL connections. Even the busiest sites and SQL servers in our farm do not come even close to this amount of connections being made to the SQL Server.
>   Below are the logs of your connections:

```
91 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
92 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
93 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
94 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
95 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
96 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
97 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
98 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
99 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
102 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
104 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
105 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
106 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
108 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
109 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
112 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
113 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
114 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
115 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
116 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
117 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
118 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
119 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
120 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
121 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
122 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
123 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
124 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
125 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
126 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
127 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
128 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
129 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
130 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
131 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
132 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
133 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
134 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
135 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
136 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
137 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
138 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
139 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
140 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
141 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
142 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
143 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
144 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
145 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
146 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
147 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
148 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
149 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
150 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
151 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
152 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
153 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
154 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
155 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
156 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
157 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
158 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
159 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
160 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
161 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
162 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
163 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
164 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
165 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
166 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
167 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
168 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
169 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
170 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
171 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
172 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
173 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
174 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
175 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
176 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
177 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
178 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
179 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
180 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
181 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
182 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
183 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
184 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
185 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
186 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
187 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
188 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
189 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
190 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
191 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
192 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
193 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
194 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
195 0 sleeping  mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
196 0 sleeping mydb PSS003 0 mydb AWAITING COMMAND 0
```

How can I prevent this problem?

Comment: Dear @Mithran, I cannot differentiate where your question ends and your log begins. Please format a bit more. Also, is this the SQL error logs you have attached? What version of SQL server is this, and is your DB set to AUTO CLOSE?

Answer (score 5):

What connection log is this?  SQL can handle thousands of connections at a time without issue.  What makes you think that it's the database which is causing the problem?  Can you connect to the database and issue commands with SQL Management Studio?  If so then it isn't the database and it is probably a problem with the app.